# How to pass token in header section in authorization field in angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-cli

I got token and stored in "this.token" as

```
this.token = Venktoken;      
console.log(this.token);
```

When I tried to pass the token values in header section am not getting any results. I tired to pass like,

```
{headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Authorization': 'bearer '+ this.token,
```

How to pass the token in header section

Comment: let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'bearer '+ this.token,
 });

return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data, { headers: headers })

Comment: where is store your token ?

Comment: you can pass token when api call

Comment: Thanks @Umesh, getting message as "Authorization has been denied for this request" in the network tab and in the console area, getting message as "401 (Unauthorized)"

Comment: token not pass in api. can show the method how you call api

Comment: I have created a stackblitz and the link is "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifi2zs" and I worked on 4 files - app.component.ts,app.component.html,app.module.ts and people.service.ts

Comment: fetchPeople() api get error so the token not get

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

`import { HttpClient, HttpResponse ,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';`

```
let header = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token);

return this.http.post(this.api_url,null, header);
```

To set **multiple** headers, try like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('InstanceName', 'ORISSA');

return this.http.post(this.api_url,null, headers );
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrita Sharma, I need to pass one more parameter like - `var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'";` in the header. I have passed like this `let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token);
     return this.http.post(url,data1, { headers: headers })` but getting error as "he request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource"

Comment: Thanks @Adrita Shama for your response, but am getting now as "401 (Unauthorized)" in console and in the network tab am getting "Authorization has been denied for this request.". However in the network tab am getting the token values, but when I tried to pass the same in the below code am getting error.

Comment: My code is ``fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string) {  this.token = Venktoken; console.log(this.token);let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo";  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token).set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('InstanceName', 'ORISSA'); return this.http.post(url, headers)    };`

Comment: "401 (Unauthorized)" means the token you are passing is invalid or expired

Comment: the issue with your http post method call. please pass null after url.
return this.http.post(url, null, headers);

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the best way of handling Authentication headers in Angular > 4 it's best to use
Http Interceptors for adding them to each request, and afterwards using
Guards for protecting your routes.

Here's a full example of an AuthInterceptor that I'm using in my app:

> auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Accept'       : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`,
      },
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

---

You'll need to register your interceptor in the app.module as a provider:

> app.module.ts

---

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from '../auth/auth.interceptor';

...

imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
],
providers: [
    {
      provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi   : true,
    },
    ...
],

...
```

---

Visit https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Regarding the Go's side of things, this is most likely a case of mismatch between
Request Headers you're sending and the headers CORS allow.
First thing you should try is allowing all of them:

```
headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
```

And if the problem goes away try carefully structuring your CORS one by one to what your client is sending.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative method you can try to use this library [angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt) It provides a [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) out of the box which automatically attaches token to `HttpClient` requests.

Also it has lots of build-in helpers like `isTokenExpired`, `decodeToken`, etc within [JwtHelperService](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/projects/angular-jwt/src/lib/jwthelper.service.ts). You can set it up as a module:

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    // ...
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
  }
});
```

> The above example using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) but you can store the token
>   anywhere on the client based on your exact use-case.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

```
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    this.http.put(`${url}`, null, { headers });

    this.http.get(`${url}`, { headers });

    this.http.delete(`${url}`, { headers });
```

**More Details (*How I found out*)?**

When you hover on the function you will find `headers` under `options` ***object*** not directly.

headers can be of type `HttpHeaders` or ***string***. I prefer using `HttpHeaders` as I showed you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I have got similar problem like this and this works for me**

1. create a **constant** called httpOptions to catch the value of headers:

```
    const httpOptions = { 
headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'my-auth-token',
  })
};
```

2. Inside of your **service** create get method that holds your token value, and set the httpOptions header to what you have got from that method.

```
    getUser(myToken:any){
     httpOptions.headers = httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization',myToken);
    
     return this.http.get(this.usersUrl,httpOptions);
    }
```

3. call the **service** inside your **component** and pass the token value:

```
    this.auth.getUser(this.tokenValue).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
      }
    )
```